# Does $\sin ^n x$ converge uniformly on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Does $f_n(x)=\sin ^n x$ converge uniformly  on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ ?

I know $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, since $\vert \sin ^n x \vert< 1$. How about the uniform convergence?

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_n=\sin ^{-1} (1-\frac 1 n)$. Then  $\sin^{n} (x_n))=(1-\frac 1 n )^{n} \to 1/e$. So the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Oh..! $x_n=\sin ^{-1} \Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n} \Bigr) $ is the sequence in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ with $f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)$ does not tend to zero, so the convergence is not uniform. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f(x) = 0$ would require that
$$
 M_n = \sup \{ |f_n(x) - f(x) | : 0 \le x < \frac \pi 2 \}  
$$
converges to zero. However,  for each $n$
$$
 M_n \ge \lim_{x \to \pi /2} f_n(x) = 1 \, .
$$

Comment: Martin.You were faster+1).Shall delete mine.